# poetry: how to adjust parallel config?

Tags: python-poetry

poetry is downloading packages in parallel (`installer.parallel=true`). What config can be adjusted if I need to control how many parallel downloads I want to have? The documentation did not list it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is:

> installer.max-workers

which is defined here:

https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/configuration/#installermax-workers

Comment: Be aware that this option is only available from the current preview release (1.2.0a2) onward.

Comment: @derek Thing is... it doesn't say how to give it that parameter.

Comment: @rjurney `poetry config installer.max-workers 28`. I have 24 cores.